# Can somebody diagram this sentence for me please?

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax

**No parking is allowed here.**

No parking is a *noun phrase* (determiner + gerund), but I'm not quite sure for "is allowed here". Is "here" a determiner? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No parking is allowed here.

You are right that "no parking" is a noun phrase (functioning here as subject), but "here" is not a determinative.

"Is allowed here" is a verb phrase functioning as predicate. "Is" is the predicator (verb) and "allowed here" is a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "is".

"Here" is traditionally analysed as an adverb, but modern grammar considers it an intransitive preposition, a locative one, typically meaning "in/at this place".

https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/here